# How to read sorted files using cat in shell script

Tags: shell, sorting, concatenation

I'm fairly new in this world, so facing this simple problem..

I'm trying to concatenate some files to a single file 'average_all'. The files are by default sorted like below:

1. aveS0
2. aveS100
3. aveS125
4. aveS150
5. aveS175
6. aveS200
7. aveS225
8. aveS25
9. .
10. .
11. .

so when I use

```
cat aveS* > average_all
```

it reads and then concatenates them according to the sort as above, but I really want it to be concatenated numerically like this:

1. aveS0
2. aveS25
3. aveS50
4. aveS75
5. aveS100
6. .
7. .

I know that `ls -1v aveS*` command will sort the files numerically but when I try to use 'cat' command it always reads from the default sort. Any idea how can I make it read the files in a numerical order and concatenate in the same manner? Hope I made it clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs` is your friend in this case. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility

Comment: well yeah, you still need that `-1v` of course, otherwise you're just using default sorting again.